# error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers uint32_t int;

Tags: c

Given the following test.c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    uint8_t byte;
    uint16_t word;
    uint32_t int;
} subsystem_data_type;

int subsystem_get_data(subsystem_data_type * outptr);

int main() {
    printf("testing\r\n");
    return 1;
}
```

I've tried to compile with the command `gcc -I. test.c` but got the following error:

```
test.c:8:14: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
     uint32_t int;
              ^
test.c:8:17: warning: declaration does not declare anything
     uint32_t int;
             ^
```

Is it possible to (kind of) redefine the int (`uint32_t int;`)? What I'm missing?

This is part of a bigger peace of code I'm studying. Please, take a look at page 8, the subsystem.h code at http://gomspace.com/documents/GS-CSP-1.1.pdf. What might be motivating the `uint32_t int;`?

Comment: And you did not even notice `int` is highlighted as a built-in type?

Comment: I did. I've edited the question, please take a look at the reference.

Comment: I will not, as the compiler already answered your question. If you see that in some document, this is a good hint to be very careful about the correctness of the rest of its contents.

Comment: The code in that PDF document is simply incorrect. See [my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32698325/827263).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is a reserved word, and the name of a predefined type. Since it's a reserved word, you can't use it as an identifier. You'll need to pick a different name.

`byte` and `word`, though they're not reserved words or predefined types, are plausible type names, so I suggest not using them as member names either. They're perfectly legal, but choosing different names could avoid confusion.

Looking at the [pdf document](http://gomspace.com/documents/GS-CSP-1.1.pdf) linked in your question, the code on page 8 is quite simply incorrect. There's nothing special about code in a PDF document that's been published on the web that makes it immune from errors. (The paragraph following the code misspells "function" as "funciton", another indication of poor proofreading.) You might want to contact the author of that document. In any case, the code was meant as a generic *example* of writing a subsystem API, not as code to be compiled and used. (But IMHO that's no excuse for this kind of error; if you're going to publish source code, you should at least verify that it compiles.)

Comment: The name spaces for type and member names do not overlap, what you say in the second paragraph is not an issue.

Comment: @Keith Thompson I've added a reference at the end of the question.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I understand that; see the updated last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint32_t int;
```

Use a different name . `int` is keyword in c used to declare variable with integer type.

Since these reserved words are meant to perform function in C program and should not be used as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to `#define` it, but you shouldn't do that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdint.h>

#define int a_integer_value

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    uint8_t byte;
    uint16_t word;
    uint32_t int;
} subsystem_data_type;

/* change int to signed to avoid confliction */
signed subsystem_get_data(subsystem_data_type * outptr);

signed main() {
    printf("testing\r\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @LeeTaylor Please tell me what the error is. [The compiler](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Rzyd3f4xAjmVR2ZI) says nothing.

Comment: `int` is a reserved word. You can't just change it's meaning. How about `#defining for somethingelse`, for example?...

Comment: @LeeTaylor: As far as the preprocessor is concerned, there are no reserved words; they're recognized only during later translation phases. `int` is just another identifier, and defining it as a macro name is legal. But it's a *really really* bad idea.

Comment: +1 for a technically correct answer. -1 for a horrible solution for something that should be fixed by changing the member name.

Comment: Yes, I know that you *can* do it. I was just pointing out that it's a horrible route to go down to start replacing one reserved word with a different word.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, as the code in the question is not from the author of the question (it is from the pdf author) why give a -1 to the question author?

Comment: @KcFnMi: Why ask me? I didn't downvote the question. (I considered downvoting this answer but decided not to; the "+1" and "-1" in my previous comment were at least partly a joke.)